# Docker install failed on downloading ubuntu package

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I'm trying to install Docker CE 18.03 on Ubuntu 18.04 using the official step by step page found [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#install-docker-ce). I am stuck at step 4) `sudo apt-get update`. This is what I get:

```
Hit:1 http://mirror.transip.net/stack/software/deb/Ubuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
Hit:2 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease 
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease 
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release 
Hit:5 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease 
Hit:6 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease 
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease 
Err:8 https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker InRelease 
403 Forbidden [IP: 52.85.58.66 443]
Reading package lists... Done 
E: Failed to fetch http://get.docker.io/ubuntu/dists/docker/InRelease 403 Forbidden [IP: 52.85.58.66 443]
E: The repository 'http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Visiting the link in Err:8 https://get.docker.com/ubuntu/ outputs the following:

```
echo "# WARNING! This script is deprecated. Please use the script"
echo "# at https://get.docker.com/"
exit 1
```

Ok, obsolete link, no problem, so I download the script found at get.docker.com and run it with bash, this is the result:

```
# Executing docker install script, commit: 36b78b2
+ sudo -E sh -c apt-get update -qq >/dev/null
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/colingille/freshlight/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
E: Failed to fetch http://get.docker.io/ubuntu/dists/docker/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 52.85.58.48 443]
E: The repository 'http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker InRelease' is not signed.
```

Is there anything I can try?

Answer (score 0):

This error means it is not able to connect to the url mentioned..

I solved using below steps..

found out which file it is there

cd /etc/apt

grep -irl "docker"

sources.list.d/docker.list

vi sources.list.d/docker.list

change the content inside this file to

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
```

save it

and then try update again.

Solved my issue!

Answer (score 0):

You're accessing from a country that Docker blocked on their server, or at least your IP 52.85.58.66

Try to use a VPN and see it if still get you the same error.

Answer (score 0):

go to the this URL or whatever that is best for your current instaltion of Ubuntu and https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/jammy/pool/stable/amd64/
and get the deb files you need.