# problems updating docker on Ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to update docker on my ubuntu server.
To do this, I am first trying to uninstall docker, but I am having some strange issues.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.6, build 369ce74a3c
$ sudo snap disable docker
error: snap "docker" is not installed
$ whereis docker
docker: /usr/bin/docker /etc/docker /usr/libexec/docker /usr/share/man/man1/docker.1.gz
$ sudo snap remove --purge docker
snap "docker" is not installed
```

so it is there and not there? any help would be great.

Comment: It looks the `docker` installed on your system not with `snap`, else might be with `apt`. That's why you are unable to disable it with `snap`. Try `apt` instead to remove. 
Hope this will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/935569/how-to-completely-uninstall-docker

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now I have an issue with installing the newest version... 

``` sudo apt-get update
``` 

and then I get 

```Err:9 https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker InRelease
  403  Forbidden [IP: 18.173.5.117 443]
```

Comment: You could check out this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468140/docker-install-failed-on-downloading-ubuntu-package

It deals exactly with what you are describing.

Comment: May be have a look at here.. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1172300/how-do-i-get-around-error-403-when-installing-docker-ce-on-ubuntu-19-04,   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51468140/docker-install-failed-on-downloading-ubuntu-package